# React native: Why does stylesheet.create return object with numbers and not styles?

Tags: react-native

I created styles, but sometimes I cannot use them because they return numbers:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    moodSliderContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '100%'
    },
    postListContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        paddingBottom: 120
    }
});
console.log(styles);
```

[image]

Comment: you should be able to use them without any problem, you see them as numbers because when you use `create` you are creating references of those styles

Comment: @jose920405 `console.log(styles.container)` in a `render` function also returns a number, how can I get the styles?

Comment: @LeonGoodLife if you're talking about using the style inside render; just  do "<View style={styles.container} />". If you want to get the values inside a specific object inside the styles; then you can use flatten function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [React Native documentation - StyleSheet](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html):

> Performance:
>
> - Making a stylesheet from a style object makes it possible to refer to it by ID instead of creating a new style object every time.
> - It also allows to send the style only once through the bridge. All subsequent uses are going to refer an id (not implemented yet).

If you want to retrieve the actual style object, you can use `StyleSheet.flatten(styles.container)`.

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheet is used to reduce **processing time** and **optimize performance**.

The numbers are a reference to the original `stylesheet` object. You can check that numbers would be unique per stylesheet and there would be no overlap.

Therefore it makes sense to replace them with numbers. It is similar concept to `Images` path storage in `react-native`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably for reusability. Consider the number as index in a table. For e.g., in your case, the container styles are stored at 219

```
BigStylesMap = { 
    219: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
    }
    ...otherCachedStyles
}
```

If it finds some other place where similar styles are defined, it can refer to the same object.